# How are called these "widgets" in Gtk+?

Tags: c, gtk, kde-plasma, gtk3

How are called these "widgets" in Gtk+: the widget with blue border and the widgets inside on it? is there equivalent in Gtk+?

Note: I'm calling "widget" by following Gtk terminology, because I don't know what its real nomenclature in the KDE environment.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is called a `TreeView`­­­­­­­, inside it you will find `TreeViewColumn` and `CellRenderer`.

The documentation is [here](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkTreeView.html).